# Link posts together (relative, not grouped)

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy

I have a Custom post type called 'Stories', which holds 'stories'.

I need a way to link stories together.

For example, i have Story A. I need a way to define story B as a relative to story A. I could do this with taxonomies, but i need a more 'relative' way not a 'grouped' way.

Any ideas?

Comment: By 'relative' do you mean ordered or related?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at scribu's [post2post plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) which allows you to create many-to-many relationships between posts of all types.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom fields containing the ID for the post(s) you want to be related.